# How to catch java exceptions in Delphi code

Tags: java, android, delphi, exception

I'm writing a Delphi/Android app that access the Google Drive API, through JNI. I need to call a Java method and catch any exceptions that occur. So how do you catch Java exceptions in Delphi? I also need the exception object to get an intent from this.

I have searched in the net and found some information about Env ExceptionCheck. I think I can possibly get the exception class this way, but how to get the exception object?

Java code looks like this:

```java
try {
    new Builder(
        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
        new GsonFactory(),
        DriveLoginFragment.this.mCredential
    ).setApplicationName("My App").build();
}
catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
    DriveLoginFragment.this.startActivityForResult(
        e.getIntent(),
        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    return null;
}
```

Delphi code looks like this:

```pascal
Drive := TJDrive_Builder.JavaClass.init(
  TJAndroidHttp.JavaClass.newCompatibleTransport,
  TJGsonFactory.JavaClass.init,
  GoogleAccountCredential
)
.setApplicationName(StringToJString('My app'))
.build;
```

Comment: Can you describe what you're going to do with the exception object once you have it?

Comment: I want to start an activity with the intent. if you look at the javacode, when it catches an UserRecoverableAuthIOException it gets the intent from the the exception object, and issues a startActivityforResult with this intent.

Comment: You *might* be able to use the setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler method on the Thread class, the main problem being that you need to pass an instance of a descendant of UncaughtExceptionHandler that overrides the uncaughtException method. This requires some Java code because presently descendants of Java classes cannot be done in Delphi

Answer (score 0):

I did what Dave Nottage suggested. I coded a little java.

I made a java library with the following class:

```
package com.softmagic.androidutils;

import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

interface ExpListener {
    void onException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable);

}

public class DelphiHandleExceptions implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        listenerInt.onException(thread, throwable);
    }

    ExpListener listenerInt;

    public DelphiHandleExceptions(ExpListener listener) {

        listenerInt = listener;
    }

}
```

i ran it through java2op, and got the following:

```
unit AndroidApi.JNI.AndroidUtils;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
// ===== Forward declarations =====

  Jandroidutils_BuildConfig = interface;//com.softmagic.androidutils.BuildConfig
  JDelphiHandleExceptions = interface;//com.softmagic.androidutils.DelphiHandleExceptions
  JExpListener = interface;//com.softmagic.androidutils.ExpListener

// ===== Interface declarations =====

  Jandroidutils_BuildConfigClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{EE706AD2-1C35-46DF-BA16-6B6C82A32336}']
    {class} function _GetAPPLICATION_ID: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetBUILD_TYPE: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetDEBUG: Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetFLAVOR: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetVERSION_CODE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetVERSION_NAME: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function init: Jandroidutils_BuildConfig; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property APPLICATION_ID: JString read _GetAPPLICATION_ID;
    {class} property BUILD_TYPE: JString read _GetBUILD_TYPE;
    {class} property DEBUG: Boolean read _GetDEBUG;
    {class} property FLAVOR: JString read _GetFLAVOR;
    {class} property VERSION_CODE: Integer read _GetVERSION_CODE;
    {class} property VERSION_NAME: JString read _GetVERSION_NAME;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/softmagic/androidutils/BuildConfig')]
  Jandroidutils_BuildConfig = interface(JObject)
    ['{2F38FDFA-A06E-486C-A2F1-9736596BFD14}']
  end;
  TJandroidutils_BuildConfig = class(TJavaGenericImport<Jandroidutils_BuildConfigClass, Jandroidutils_BuildConfig>) end;

  JDelphiHandleExceptionsClass = interface(JThread_UncaughtExceptionHandlerClass)
    ['{E39A8542-DF8B-4880-8286-C4BD9993F6CE}']
    {class} function init(P1: JExpListener): JDelphiHandleExceptions; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure uncaughtException(P1: JThread; P2: JThrowable); cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/softmagic/androidutils/DelphiHandleExceptions')]
  JDelphiHandleExceptions = interface(JThread_UncaughtExceptionHandler)
    ['{B8AC378F-9FCA-4661-95E0-BA73736E6426}']
  end;
  TJDelphiHandleExceptions = class(TJavaGenericImport<JDelphiHandleExceptionsClass, JDelphiHandleExceptions>) end;

  JExpListenerClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{AC1C06C0-B5D4-4952-9076-5AAAE941703C}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/softmagic/androidutils/ExpListener')]
  JExpListener = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{DC8FC3DE-029F-4127-90AA-AABC2081B78B}']
    procedure onException(P1: JThread; P2: JThrowable); cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;
  TJExpListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JExpListenerClass, JExpListener>) end;

implementation

procedure RegisterTypes;
begin
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('AndroidApi.JNI.AndroidUtils.Jandroidutils_BuildConfig', TypeInfo(AndroidApi.JNI.AndroidUtils.Jandroidutils_BuildConfig));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('AndroidApi.JNI.AndroidUtils.JDelphiHandleExceptions', TypeInfo(AndroidApi.JNI.AndroidUtils.JDelphiHandleExceptions));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('AndroidApi.JNI.AndroidUtils.JExpListener', TypeInfo(AndroidApi.JNI.AndroidUtils.JExpListener));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTypes;
end.
```

I made the following declarations:

```
   JavaExceptionListener: TJavaExceptionListener;
   DefUncaughtExceptionHandler: JThread_UncaughtExceptionHandler;
   DelphiHandleExceptions: JDelphiHandleExceptions;
```

In my FormCreate method i entered:

```
   JavaExceptionListener := TJavaExceptionListener.Create;
   DefUncaughtExceptionHandler := TJThread.JavaClass.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler;
   DelphiHandleExceptions := 
   TJDelphiHandleExceptions.JavaClass.init(JavaExceptionListener);
   TJThread.JavaClass.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(DelphiHandleExceptions);
```

I defined the listener:

```
  TJavaExceptionListener = class(TJavaLocal, JExpListener)
    procedure onException(P1: JThread; P2: JThrowable); cdecl;
  end;
```

and it's method:

```
procedure TJavaExceptionListener.onException(P1: JThread; P2: JThrowable);
begin

  if TJNIResolver.IsInstanceOf(P2, TJUserRecoverableAuthIOException.GetClsID)
  then
     begin
        TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivityForResult(TJUserRecoverableAuthIOException.Wrap(P2).getIntent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        Exit;
     end;

  DefUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(P1, P2);

end;
```

I haven't tested it yet. My app is not ready for test. I think this will work.